# React-Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am new to ReactJS and having trouble using the react-bootstrap navbar. I could use guidance as there's little or no information on this.

When I create a component and write the below coding and run the site its load infinitely

```js
//index.js

import React from 'react'
import { Nav, NavDropdown, Form, FormControl, Button } from "react-bootstrap"


function Navbar(){
    return (
      <>
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#">Navbar scroll</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
        <Nav className="mr-auto my-2 my-lg-0" style={{ maxHeight: '100px' }} navbarScroll >
          <Nav.Link href="#action1">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#action2">Link</Nav.Link>
          <NavDropdown title="Link" id="navbarScrollingDropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action3">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action4">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action5">Something else here</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          <Nav.Link href="#" disabled>
            Link
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        <Form className="d-flex">
          <FormControl
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            className="mr-2"
            aria-label="Search"
          />
          <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
        </Form>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
        
      </>
    )
};
```